# Butchering criticism?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Could "butcher" work as criticism?

> “I doubt [we'll be hearing from him], especially after we butchered him in that interview,”

Comment: Sure, that's fine and pretty idiomatic.

Comment: I thought so, but I after so long with the text I can't see it anymore

Comment: Although it's not clear who had which role(s) in the interview, nor whether the outcome as described was intentional or accidental.

Comment: @JohnLawler why? and so?

Comment: All that's obvious is that there are at least three people involved; the speaker, the referent _he/him_, and somebody else allied with the speaker. _He/him_ was interviewed by the speaker and somebody else, and the interview went badly, in at least someone's opinion. But all that _butcher_ means is that there was blood on the ground, not that it was supposed to be there, or that it was part of a systematic activity; and it's not clear whose opinion of "butchery" is being discussed. There's simply no context in one sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Let me make this short - the role relations you assumed, right or wrong, as well as the allied intentions towards the referent, whatever they might be, cannot interfere with the context relevant to the question. So why did I have to read through all that? If you want a more punishing analysis of how your points are all worse than moot, I'll make it available. We can also both delete our comments and never speak of this horror again. The only possible need for more context would be to satisfy some curiousity, in which case tell me and I'll send you the book when it's out.

Comment: Generally you'd use "butcher" as an attribute of the person/group being critiqued.  Eg, the orchestra butchered the symphony.  It's not usually something to brag about.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the usual idiomatic use of butcher, I'm not sure I've ever seen butcher used in this sense. When you say you butchered someone you are saying that you have killed them, probably in a brutal and messy way. One might say that someone has butchered a situation or task, which would mean that they've mangled it through carelessness or incompetence.

I don't think anyone will read that sentence and assume anything other than what you've intended, but it's awkward and feels non-native.

Answer (score 1):

"Butchered" has several figurative meanings, not all consistent with each other:

- If you totally "flubbed" a speech, for example, you "butchered" it.
- If an editor totally rewrites your literary effort (in a way you do not like), he "butchered" it.
- If you were being interviewed on a TV show and the host kept asking questions intended to make you look stupid or otherwise made you look bad he "butchered" you.
- And, of course (not so figurative), if some combatant in war or other mayhem wreaks havoc on the inhabitants of a village, not only killing them but often dismembering their bodies, etc, then they were "butchered".
- And likely a few other scenarios.